# Android change multiple UI elements

Tags: android, animation, asynchronous

I want to change multiple textviews (>30) at the same time in short time steps. but the changes are very laggy if these steps are to short (<100ms). i want to archieve ~10ms. im debugging on a nexus 4. is that behaviour normal?
heres my code:

```
public class AsyncChangeUI extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    View view;
    int oldPercentage;
    int newPercentage;

    AsyncChangeUI(View view, int oldPercentage, int newPercentage){
        super();
        this.view = view;
        this.oldPercentage = oldPercentage;
        this.newPercentage = newPercentage;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.e("Kachel", view.getClass().getName());

        for(Integer i=this.oldPercentage; i<=newPercentage; i++){
            this.oldPercentage = i;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(10); //laggy if <100
                publishProgress(i);
            }catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        List<TileGroupLayout> tileGroupList = ((MainLinearLayout) view).tileGroupList;

        for (TileGroupLayout tileGroup: tileGroupList) {
            List<TileLayout> tileList = tileGroup.tileList;

            for (TileLayout tile: tileList) {
                tile.changePercentageTo(progress[0]);
            }  
        }       
    }
}
```

thx!
i noticed that the the last steps of changing are more laggy than the first:S

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this without the debugger connected? The debugger realy slows your application down.

Comment: yes, without any effect. do you know any percentage of how strong the effect may be?